# Convert NSAttributedString to Microsoft Word

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

In Apple documentation there seems to be a method that does [this conversion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1528592-docformat), but it does not show up in Xcode 8 with Swift 3.

I get the error:

> Value of type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'docFormat'

Comment: It is function, not property

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov can you please explain how can I use this function?

Comment: Could it be that the function only available on macOS, not on iOS?

Comment: @MartinR damn that's right, I've missed that. If you have any idea how to convert it to Data object then would be happy to get help on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107629/post-nsattributedstring-with-images-to-server